# OpenXML Spreadsheet how to deal with both writing to new and existing file

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am developing an application that will deal with spreadsheets using OpenXML and needs to be able to handle the following scenarios:

1. Create a new spreadsheet and save it (SAX friendly)
2. Open an existing spreadsheet and edit it (DOM required)

For (1) I have already set up my own classes to store worksheets, cell values and styles, graphs etc and write the spreadsheet with the SAX method using the `OpenXmlWriter` for performance.

For (2) it seems like there needs to be a completely different approach (i.e. branch my application in two "modes"), having completely different code for doing the same thing to a new spreadsheet and an existing one. For example, to write values to cells I need to have two versions of the `setCellValues` function, one that writes to my own classes, and a second one which works with the DOM to find and update values to existing cells.

An alternative to (2) would be reading a big chunk of the spreadsheet's functionality (styles, drawings etc) in my own classes to be able to use (1) for all scenarios, which I'm not keen on doing, as it will force me to support much more OpenXML functionality than my requirements.

From what I've read in other questions, it seems that using the SAX approach to edit existing files is not possible.
My question is: Is there a way to handle both scenarios without having to write the same functions once for each scenario?